# Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, mysqli

For my application i'm creating a group where members can subscribe. With the function CreateGroup i'm writing data to the database. with the sql '`$insert`' i'm writing data to `tblgroups`. That's ok

With the sql '`$insertmember`' i'm trying to send data to `tblgroup_member` but `group_id` and `groupmember_id` won't fill up.

The `group_id` has to be the `id_number` of the last created group. Therefore i'm using the sql '`$latest`'. After that i'm doing `fetch_assoc` to get the number.

But I get the error that `$latestresult` is undefined en that the `mysqli::query` is empty? What I'm a doing wrong?

PHP

```
$user_id = $user -> getUserByEmail($email);

if(isset($_POST["btnCreateGroup"])){
        try {
        $group = new Group();

         $distance  = (isset($_POST["distance"]))  ? $_POST["distance"]  : '';
         $groupname = (isset($_POST["groupname"])) ? $_POST["groupname"] : '';
          $duration  = (isset($_POST["duration"])) ? $_POST["duration"]   : '';

        $group->GroupDistance = mysql_real_escape_string($distance);
        $group->GroupName = mysql_real_escape_string($groupname);
        $group->GroupDuration = mysql_real_escape_string($duration);
        $group->CreatorId = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
        $group->CreateGroup();
        //$group->SaveCreatoridToGroup();

        } catch(exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e -> getMessage();
    }
```

FUNCTION

```
public function CreateGroup()
    {

        $db = new Db();

        $insert = "INSERT INTO tblgroups (
                     group_name,
                     group_distance,
                     group_duration,
                     group_creator_id

                  ) VALUES (
                      '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sGroupName) . "',
                       '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iGroupDistance) . "',
                         '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_iGroupDuration) . "',
                '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sCreatorId) . "'
                  )";

                  $db -> conn -> query($insert);


        $latest = "SELECT group_id FROM tblgroups ORDER BY group_id desc limit 1";
        $latestresult = $db->conn->query($latestresult);
        $fetch_latestresult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($latestresult);
        var_dump($latestresult);  

        $insertmember = "INSERT INTO tblgroup_member (
                            group_id,
                            groupmember_id

                            ) VALUES (
                            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($fetch_latestresult) . "',
                            '" . $db->conn->real_escape_string($this->m_sCreator_id) ."'
                            )";

                                      $db -> conn -> query($insertmember);
                                      throw new Exception("You created a group!");

    }
```

Comment: Obligatory comment telling you to use PDO and not mysqli. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php Or at least use prepared statements instead of escaping strings. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake

```
$latest = "SELECT group_id FROM tblgroups ORDER BY group_id desc limit 1";
$latestresult = $db->conn->query($latestresult);
```

should be

```
$latest = "SELECT group_id FROM tblgroups ORDER BY group_id desc limit 1";
$latestresult = $db->conn->query($latest);
```

Comment: Now he is telling me this: Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...

When I do a var_dump he is giving the correct number

Comment: You need to pass in a string `real_escape_string($fetch_latestresult['group_id'])`

Comment: It's working but why do i have to tell which column i want? I did this already in the query?

Comment: because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will return associative array